# How to display row data in columns is ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have this structure in my data which is read off of a SP.
[image]

the 2 rows are pretty much identical except for the column4 and column5 columns. I need to display this:

[image]

How should I do the groupings in the tablix/table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of Tablix you can use Matrix and use Column 4 and Column 5 in column group. It's much simpler I guess. Design looks like below:[image]

and result is:
[image]

Comment: happy to help. Please mark as answer and up vote if it helped :)